# Improve two similar queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have these queries :

```
initial_date = NewUser.joins(:interactions)
               .where('interactions.interaction_sub_type in (?)', types)
               .where('interactions.interaction_type in (?)', actions)
               .limit(1000).order('users.id asc').minimum(:updated_at)

last_date = NewUser.joins(:interactions)
            .where('interactions.interaction_sub_type in (?)', types)
            .where('interactions.interaction_type in (?)', actions)
            .limit(1000).order('users.id asc').maximum(:updated_at)
```

They are almost the same, except for the `minimum` and `maximum`.
I'm trying to improve this code, but I have no idea on how to change this.
I thought of something like

```
base = NewUser.joins(:interactions)
                   .where('interactions.interaction_sub_type in (?)', types)
                   .where('interactions.interaction_type in (?)', actions)
                   .limit(1000).order('users.id asc')
initial_date = base.minimum(:updated_at)
```

but for some reason, this doesn't work. Seems like ActiveRecord execute the query for the `base` and then executes again on `initial_date`.

Comment: Whats wrong with your solution? Do you get an error or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you consider using a [`scope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes):

```
# in your `new_user` Model
scope :with_interactions, ->(types, actions) {
  where('interactions.interaction_sub_type in (?)', types).
    where('interactions.interaction_type in (?)', actions).
    limit(1000).order('users.id asc')
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
initial_date = NewUser.with_interactions(types, actions).minimum(:updated_at)
last_date    = NewUser.with_interactions(types, actions).maximum(:updated_at)
```

Comment: Correct and `Rails` way of doing it.

Comment: this is just perfect! how come I haven't thought about it?

Answer (score 1):

It's has been a long time since I worked on Rails, but I would like to take a shot.

```
NewUser.joins(:interactions)
       .select("MIN(updated_at) AS initial_date, MAX(updated_at) AS last_date")
       .where('interactions.interaction_sub_type in (?)', types)
       .where('interactions.interaction_type in (?)', actions)
       .limit(1000).order('users.id asc')
```

It will return a result with 2 columns, `initial_date` and `last_date`